# LT317 charger LTspice simulation acting weird

Tags: circuit-design, voltage-regulator, ltspice, charger

I am currently trying to design the constant-voltage charging block for a Li-ion charger as a part of a course project. The charger block has an [LT317](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/lt0117.pdf) regulating the charging voltage to ~16.8V and an [LM358](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm158-n.pdf) in a voltage-subtractor configuration to measure the voltage over a 0R1 shunt.
In order to validate the idea, I'm simulating the charger block in LTspice. Now for some reason, I am not getting the expected value of 16.8V at the Vout node, but instead closer to 15.5V:
[image: unexpected simulation result]

I've noticed that this has something to do with the shunt resistor, as when I set it to 0R, I get the expected output voltage:
[image: expected simulation result]

What I now would like to know, is if this is caused by the simulation, or my design? As I don't have all the components on hand I can't really validate this further at the moment.

Comment: What are the voltages and currents in the circuit? You have the circuit in the simulator so figure them out. Do you see unexpected currents or voltages anywhere?

Comment: Is there some source impedance built into V1?

Comment: You're messing up the feedback loop between the OUT and ADJ pins by including your sense resistor in the loop.  Connect R2 directly to OUT instead of after the sense resistor.